# How to get fixed day in each month in a year with golang?

Tags: go

If the input day is out of range of the month, then the end day of the month instead。

For example,

input :

```
5
```

output:

```
["2023-01-05","2023-02-05",...,"2023-12-05"]
```

intput:

```
31
```

output:

```
["2023-01-31","2023-02-28",...,"2023-11-30","2023-12-31"]
```

Comment: What did you try? And be a bit more specific on the output? You want a slice of date strings? It is not clear

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following helper functions to normalize a list of date strings into the form that you would like (if the input day is out of range, use the end day of the month instead)

```golang
func getLastDayOfMonth(t time.Time) time.Time {
    lastDayOfMonth := time.Date(t.Year(), t.Month()+1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, time.UTC)
    return lastDayOfMonth
}

func formatSlices(dates []string) []string {
    var formattedDates []string
    for _, date := range dates {
        dateSlice := strings.Split(date, "-")
        rawDate, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02", dateSlice[0]+"-"+dateSlice[1]+"-01")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        lastDayOfMonth := getLastDayOfMonth(rawDate)
        newDate := date
        rawDay, err := strconv.Atoi(dateSlice[2])
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        if lastDayOfMonth.Day() < rawDay {
            newDate = dateSlice[0] + "-" + dateSlice[1] + "-" + strconv.FormatInt(int64(lastDayOfMonth.Day()), 10)
        }
        formattedDates = append(formattedDates, newDate)
    }
    return formattedDates
}
```

Full code: https://go.dev/play/p/D_yWY76GyLh